# How can I assign smarty var that is only translated once and repeated in a template?

Tags: prestashop-1.6, smarty3

I tried to use the following to assign a `var` and put translation to it but failed.

```
{assign var="figcaption" value="{l s='Free Migration or Installation' mod='twittercard'}"}
```

When I try to use the smarty `var {$figcaption}` now, I get an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**{capture}** is used to collect the output of the template between the tags into a variable instead of displaying it. Any content between **{capture name='foo'}** and **{/capture}** is collected into the variable specified in the *name* attribute.

```
{capture name="figcaption"}{l s="Free Migration or Installation" mod="twittercard"}{/capture}
    {$smarty.capture.figcaption}
```

Use http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl

Comment: Shouldn't there be single ticks around `name='figcaption'`?

Comment: I changed answer with full correct syntax, you can use single quotes if you want

Comment: How would you rate my question? ;-)

Comment: not sure what are you asking about, it's just documentation, not a problem solving ;)

Comment: No one has rated my question, yet.